# Which data type to use for time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I don't know what data type is needed to store time in mysqlite table, my database should look like this. Time: Hint. For hint is varchar but for time?

```
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS settime (time #which# auto_increment primary key, hints varchar(50))')
```

Comment: What purpose does the time serve in your application? Is it a timestamp? A duration? Something else?

Comment: If you envision needing any of the SQLite [date functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), use a format that is supported by them: (a) ISO-8601 strings (b) Julian days (ew) (c) UNIX timestamps. Since the functions "natively" like (a), I'd go with that.

Comment: You should wonder whether you will want to do operations on those datatypes. Getting a duration between 2 numeric values is more easy than between  2 ISO-8601 strings. On the other hand, if you need absolute precision ISO-8601 may be better.

Answer (score 0):

In short there are many ways. However:-

The most efficient way of storing time is to store it as an integer. The type itself (unless the column is defined as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY) doesn't actually matter, as SQLite is flexible with column types allowing virtually any type to be specified.

Furthermore SQLite, with the exception of the rowid column, or an alias of the rowid column, and more recently of if the table is a [Strict Table](https://www.sqlite.org/stricttables.html); then any type of value can be stored in any type of column.

Consider the following, based upon your create (note that in SQLITE the keyword is [AUTOINCREMENT](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), not *AUTO_INCREMENT*, it is not recommended to use the keyword, it probably is not required).

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS settime;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS settime (
    time INTEGER DEFAULT (strftime('%s','now')), 
    hints virtually_any_type_can_used_even_rumplestiltskin, 
    another_time virtually_any_type_can_used_even_rumplestiltskinm DEFAULT (strftime('%s','now'))
);

INSERT INTO settime (hints) VALUES('hint1');
INSERT INTO settime (hints) VALUES('hint2');
INSERT INTO settime (hints) VALUES('hint3');
INSERT INTO settime VALUES (randomblob(16),randomblob(16),randomblob(32));
SELECT *, datetime(time,'unixepoch') AS visualtime FROM settime;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS settime; /* CLEANUP */
```

When run via an SQLite Tool (Navicat used for the example) the output shows:-

[image]

The output might appear confusing, especially the last row. The last row shows that you can store any type (a BLOB) in any column type (see above for exceptions). That is a randomly generated blob has bee stored in all 3 columns.

Instead of 2 columns, time and hint, a third column another_time has been included, this having a ridiculous column type, as does the hints column. The column type used to demonstrate that the type is not overly important names wise and also that if has little effect in regards to storing data.

You may also notice that a DEFAULT has been specified both the time and another_time columns. This will store the current time (`now`), precise to a second, if no value is supplied when inserting a row. Hence the first 3 inserts only provide a value for the hints column.

- note that the 8 bytes, for an integer equates to a 64 bit signed number, plenty to cope with a precision down to milliseconds (but note that the `unixepoch` modifier expect the precision to be at the second level). As such is is feasible to store values down to milliseconds, just that you would have to divide by 1000 to strip the milliseconds is using the SQLite date and time functions with the `unixepoch` modifier.

The SELECT using `*` (all unhidden columns) and then `datetime(time,'unixepoch') AS visualtime` adds a derived column call visualtime. The column is a date and time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format, i.e. the integer value stored is converted using the SQLite built-in `datetime` function (not that as the date is stored in a unix format that the `unixepoch` modifier informs the function of this).

Integer values are more efficient, they take up less storage (up to 8 bytes), whilst a date as a string such as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS takes up  at least 19 bytes. An integer value requires less processing, say when sorting or comparing values. The only disadvantage is that the value is not easily read by humans.

You may wish to refer to:-

```
[Data Types in SQLite][4],
[Date and Time Functions][4],
[SQLite Autoincrement][2] (also includes much about the **`rowid`** column),
[Built-In Scalar SQL Functions][4] (such as `RandomBlob`)
```